# How do I modify wordpress search function with additional parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress website currently has the a default function for search

Upon submit event the page url appears as http://domain.com/?s=KEYWORD but I want to show the results on this url http://domain.com/?s=keyword**&para1=mypara**

What Should i modify to the search form to get the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a searchform.php template in your theme, then put everything you want.

See this:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form

**Tips: Looks at the default WordPress themes to see the sample.**